# How to select a 0.1" header in Fritzing

Tags: system-design

Does Fritzing support the standard 0.1" break-away header?

When I search for "header" in its parts database, I see several examples, and some even seem to reference 0.1 headers, but I can't actually seem to select the physical part.

For example, if I select the "Header 3" part, the description specifically refers to 0.1 break away headers, but the "package" field references a completely different part, causing it to render incorrectly. If I click that dropdown to try and select a different package, there are dozens listed, but none look like a 0.1 header.

[image]